# Azure DevOps and private git repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps, however source code is located on my private git server. I don't want to use polling, instead I want to trigger a build everytime I push something to git. Is it possible to do? How?

Comment: create a commit hook on your git server?

Comment: What this hook should do? which Azure endpoint should it call and how?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup would need to look like this:

1. Create an Azure DevOps Build pipeline with your private Git server as source
   [image]
2. Configure a Git hook (e.g. [post-recieve](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_code_post_receive_code) hook), which calls the [Azure DevOps REST-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to queue a new build

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it appears its not possible with service hooks (i thought service hooks would allow you to do that, but they are only for events originating from Azure Devops). Judging by the lack of documentation on this part - I dont think its supported, but looking at [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/469206/azure-devops-services-rest-api-50-post-endpoint-fo.html) thread it might be possible to do so without service hooks.